# Error while scraping the data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

I want to scrape the number of membership years data from the IMDB Users page. 
[Link](https://www.imdb.com/user/ur102180396) 
For this page, there are multiple badges and one badge is common for all users i.e last one.

My Code:

```
def getYear(review_url):

    response = requests.get(review_url, headers = { 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
    })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    year = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'value'})
    ## year = soup.select('.value')

    return year[-1].get_text()
```

I have referred to various sources and found that adding user-agent in headers have solved their issue but I have added the same and yet not working.

Function Call:

```
getYear('https://www.imdb.com/user/ur102180396')
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-dc3ce3a7e637> in <module>()
----> 1 getYear('https://www.imdb.com/user/ur102180396')

<ipython-input-23-5871162c538d> in getYear(review_url)
      6     year = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'value'})
      7 
----> 8     return year[-1].get_text()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error is because soup.find_all() method is returning empty list. I don't know why this is happening, I am quite new to beautifulsoup.
Weird behaviour is seen that sometimes this function is working fine and giving output, but as soon as I call this function on all the data (2136 user links), this error is obtained.

Function call for all the users:

```
years = [getYear(url) for url in user_links]
```

here user_links is list comprising 2136 users' url.

Answer (score 0):

*Weird behaviour is seen that sometimes this function is working fine and giving output, but as soon as I call this function on all the data (2136 user links), this error is obtained.*

This may be because IMDB isn't responding to your requests as you are making too many requests (2136 in this case) at once.

Comment: So will scraping data in chunks will solve the issue?